# Unable to deploy mule application with large size jar file

Tags: mulesoft, anypoint-studio, mule-esb, cloudhub

I have developed a mule application in anypoint studio which will run pySpark scripts and do some ETL operations. I have more number of dependencies added to make this work and works fine in my local. While trying to deploy to CloudHub the deployable jar is getting created with around 590MB and throwing the below error.

[image]
Below are the dependencies

```
<dependencies>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.mule.connectors</groupId>
        <artifactId>mule-sockets-connector</artifactId>
        <version>1.2.3</version>
        <classifier>mule-plugin</classifier>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.mule.connectors</groupId>
        <artifactId>mule-db-connector</artifactId>
        <version>1.14.4</version>
        <classifier>mule-plugin</classifier>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>com.mulesoft.connectors</groupId>
        <artifactId>mule-amazon-s3-connector</artifactId>
        <version>6.3.2</version>
        <classifier>mule-plugin</classifier>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>mysql</groupId>
        <artifactId>mysql-connector-java</artifactId>
        <version>8.0.30</version>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.mule.modules</groupId>
        <artifactId>mule-compression-module</artifactId>
        <version>2.2.1</version>
        <classifier>mule-plugin</classifier>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.mule.connectors</groupId>
        <artifactId>mule-file-connector</artifactId>
        <version>1.5.1</version>
        <classifier>mule-plugin</classifier>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.mule.connectors</groupId>
        <artifactId>mule-http-connector</artifactId>
        <version>1.8.0</version>
        <classifier>mule-plugin</classifier>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>com.mulesoft.connectors</groupId>
        <artifactId>mule4-amazon-redshift-connector</artifactId>
        <version>1.0.8</version>
        <classifier>mule-plugin</classifier>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.mule.module</groupId>
        <artifactId>mule-java-module</artifactId>
        <version>1.2.11</version>
        <classifier>mule-plugin</classifier>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.apache.spark</groupId>
        <artifactId>spark-core_2.12</artifactId>
        <version>3.4.1</version>
    </dependency>
    <!-- https://mvnrepository.com/artifact/org.apache.spark/spark-sql -->
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.apache.spark</groupId>
        <artifactId>spark-sql_2.12</artifactId>
        <version>3.4.1</version>
        <scope>provided</scope>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.mule.modules</groupId>
        <artifactId>mule-scripting-module</artifactId>
        <version>2.0.4</version>
        <classifier>mule-plugin</classifier>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.codehaus.groovy</groupId>
        <artifactId>groovy-all</artifactId>
        <version>2.4.21</version>
        <classifier>indy</classifier>
    </dependency>
    <!-- https://mvnrepository.com/artifact/org.apache.hudi/hudi-spark3.4-bundle -->
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.apache.hudi</groupId>
        <artifactId>hudi-spark3.4-bundle_2.12</artifactId>
        <version>0.14.0</version>
    </dependency>
    <!-- https://mvnrepository.com/artifact/org.apache.spark/spark-avro -->
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.apache.spark</groupId>
        <artifactId>spark-avro_2.13</artifactId>
        <version>3.5.0</version>
    </dependency>
    <!-- https://mvnrepository.com/artifact/org.apache.hadoop/hadoop-aws -->
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.apache.hadoop</groupId>
        <artifactId>hadoop-aws</artifactId>
        <version>3.3.4</version>
    </dependency>
    <!-- https://mvnrepository.com/artifact/org.apache.hadoop/hadoop-common -->
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.apache.hadoop</groupId>
        <artifactId>hadoop-common</artifactId>
        <version>3.3.6</version>
    </dependency>
    <!-- https://mvnrepository.com/artifact/com.github.joshelser/dropwizard-metrics-hadoop-metrics2-reporter -->
    <dependency>
        <groupId>com.github.joshelser</groupId>
        <artifactId>dropwizard-metrics-hadoop-metrics2-reporter</artifactId>
        <version>0.1.0</version>
    </dependency>
    <!-- https://mvnrepository.com/artifact/com.amazonaws/aws-java-sdk -->
    <dependency>
        <groupId>com.amazonaws</groupId>
        <artifactId>aws-java-sdk-s3</artifactId>
        <version>1.12.589</version>
    </dependency>
    <!-- <dependency>
        <groupId>com.sparkjava</groupId>
        <artifactId>spark-core</artifactId>
        <version>2.9.3</version>
    </dependency>-->
</dependencies>
```

Comment: Have you considered optimizing your dependencies? Sometimes, we end up including more than we actually need. Streamlining those could help trim down the file size significantly.

Comment: Yes. I have only those dependencies which are required. Also the application is expected to grow with more dependencies as it evolves, so looking for a way to deploy large size applications.

Comment: looking at the maximum limit error. Try tools which allow you to store and manage your dependencies externally, so your deployable JAR doesn't need to include them all. Instead, it can fetch them dynamically during runtime.

Comment: make sure that the hadoop-aws declaration excludes its "aws-java-sdk-bundle" dependency and you'll cut 500 MB off the binary. But: you are then left with the problem of getting the dependencies that the aws sdk expects consistent with the rest of your app. not fun

Comment: The maximum deployment size for an application in CloudHub 1.0 is 200MB, and for CloudHub 2.0 is currently 350MB: https://docs.mulesoft.com/cloudhub-2/ch2-limits. You need to get your application file under that or it won't deploy.

Comment: @codeapplied Mule uses its own classloaders. Fetching external dependencies somehow needs to be tested in the Mule application to see if it is feasible.

Comment: @aled what about cloud-native approaches like using containerization with Docker. This way, you can package your application along with its dependencies into a container image, which can then be easily deployed to CloudHub or any other cloud platform.

Comment: CloudHub is integration as a service. You can only deploy a Mule application.

Comment: If you want to deploy manually to your own Mule server then you are not impacted by Anypoint Platform size limits, though the question is about deploying to CloudHub.